# Click a cell to add a string to the bottom of a list

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm very new to using macros in Excel, so I hope this question isn't too silly.

I'm creating a worksheet to track sales. I've got a list of drinks in one column and I wanted to assign a macro to the cells so that when you click on them, the text in their cells is copied to another column.

I know you can record macros to copy-and-paste values, but I'm not sure how to make it copy the text in the next empty cell in the column, and not just in the first cell.

[image]

So in summary, these are my tables. I want to be able to click a cell in the **Drinks** column, and have the string appear at the bottom of the **list** column (so after 'Cuba Libre')

Thanks!

**EDIT_1:**

Ok, so here's my code so far:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
       Range("C2").Select
       Selection.Copy
       Range("A2").Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste
   End If
End Sub
```

^I've repeated this code for each of the relevant cells in column C (C2:C5).

Like I said, I've only gotten to the point of being able to copy paste the values from the **Drinks** column into the **List** column, I am lost as to how to paste the value into the next empty cell.

Comment: Note that SO is not a free code writing service. If you have made an attempt yourself, please share where you are getting stuck. Don't ask others to write the entire thing for you without showing any effort.

Comment: Right sorry my bad. I think I know how to make cells clickable, and like I said, I understand how to get it to copy-paste, what im struggling with is getting it to copy paste at the bottom of the list. From what I gather I'd need to create a loop that tests whether or not a cell is empty or not, and having it move down one row if it is, but that's where I get lost.

I'll edit my question with my attempt so far.

Comment: [This will help you](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand your check on `Target` to include the whole Drinks range.  Then determine the next available cell in List

Something like (hard coded for List in Column A and Drinks in Column C)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rDrinks As Range
    
    ' single cell has been selected
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ' Get ref to Drinks range
        Set rDrinks = Me.Range(Me.Cells(2, 3), Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
        ' Is selected cell in drinks range?
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rDrinks) Is Nothing Then
            ' add to list
            Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value2 = Target.Value2
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!

I went in another direction with the solution, but I'll be going with yours because it works perfectly.

Comment: Just checking, in case I move the columns around,
`Me.Cells(2, 3), Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 3)` Gets the **drinks** ref, so `2,3` refers to the row,column, and `Me.Rows.Count,3` is another reference to the column, correct?
And then, the _1_ in `Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count,1)` is the reference to the **list** column.

Comment: @Anze Your analysis is correct.  If the columns might move around, and you don't know in advance where they are, you'll need some way to located them. Some ideas: Named ranges, or Tables (ListObjects), or search for the headers in row (1), or something else

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
So I've managed to figure out how to get the macro to paste the cell value at the bottom of the list!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As String

   If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
       Range("C2").Select
       Selection.Copy
       LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
       Range("A" & LastRow).Activate
       ActiveSheet.Paste
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
   End If
End Sub
```

However, I've got a quality-of-life question. Is there any way to edit the code so that it applies to all the cells in the range C2:C10? Because as it stands, I would have to repeat the code for each cell replacing lines 3 & 4 for all the cells in range.

```
If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
       Range("C2").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually turn List and Drinks into tables (with those names), you could use the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    
    ' Check user has clicked on a drink
    If Not Intersect(Target, [Drinks]) Is Nothing And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ' Find first blank row in List
        For i = [List].Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            If [List].Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
                row = i
            End If
        Next
        
        ' If no blank row, add a new row
        If row = 0 Then
            ListObjects("List").ListRows.Add
            row = [List].Rows.Count
        End If
        
        [List].Cells(row, 1) = Target
    End If
End Sub
```